# Select all users in a group beside currentUser

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I'd like to select all the `users` beside the current user in a given `group`. The relationship between group and user is many-to-many.

At the moment my query selects all users in a given group.

```
SELECT g.users FROM Group g WHERE g.groupName =:groupName
```

I didn't manage to get what I wanted, I don't know where to add a condition (in the where clause the condition is not met so I have an empty list of users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a JOIN between the 2 entities:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN Group g WHERE g.groupName =: groupName
```